# JQuery .then how does the return value work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the following code:

```
function doSomething() {
    var promise = $.ajax(//...);
    return promise;
}
```

Let's use it with `then`:

```
doSomething().then(function(data) {
    return true; // this is passed to the next then
}).then(function(data){
    alert(data); // this will show true as expected
    return doSomething(); // A promise object should be passed to the next then
}).then(function(data){
    // I expected this to be the promise object but this is not a promise object. 
    // It is the response from the doSomething() AJAX call
    alert(data); 
});
```

**Question**: Why does the last `data` parameter contain the response? How does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Return_value):

> The behavior of the handler function follows a specific set of rules. If a handler function returns another **pending** promise object, the resolution/rejection of the promise returned by `then` will be subsequent to the resolution/rejection of the promise returned by the handler. Also, the value of the promise returned by `then` will be the same as the value of the promise returned by the handler.

Comment: Thanks! As I walked away from my desk I remembered reading this last night and I was about to delete the question but you beat me to it. Will accept the answer soon.